# Show that $T(n)= 2^{n+1} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Show that $T(n)= 2^{n+1} - 1$, for the following,

$$
  T(n) = \cases{        1       & if, $n=0$ \cr
                 T(n-1) + 2^n & otherwise}
$$

I did it as follows,

\begin{align*}
   T(n) = T(n-2) + 2^{n-1} + 2^n  \\
   T(n) = T(n-3) + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1} + 2^n\\
   &\vdots\\
   T(n) = T(n-(n-1)) + 2^{n-n}+ \dots+ 2^{n-1} + 2^n
\end{align*}

From the last call, I can see that,

\begin{align*}
   T(0) = T(1) + 2^{0}+ \dots+ 2^{n-1} + 2^n  \\
   1 = T(1) + 2^{0}+ \dots+ 2^{n-1} + 2^n\\
   1 = T(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}2^i\\
   1 = T(1) + \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}\\
\end{align*}

How we can get rid of 1 and T(1) as they appeared in my solution please?

Comment: Well... $T(1) = T(0) + 2^0 = 2$

Comment: @preferred_anon. :/  Thank you.

Comment: You spelled $n+1$ as $n-1$ on the RHS of the third line in your "I did it as follows..." You need to end one cycle sooner and swap sides of $T(0)$ and $T(1)$...

Comment: There is no need to solve the recurrence. Just say $2^{0+1}-1=1$ and $2^{n+1}-1=2^n-1+2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work contains a number of errors.

First of all, your equation $$T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 2^{n-1} + 2^n$$ makes no sense, since $$T(n) = T(n-1) + 2^n \tag{1}$$ from the given definition implies $$T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 2^{n-1}, \tag{2} $$ simply by replacing $n$ with $n-1$.

What you probably intended to write is

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + 2^n = \left(T(n-2) + 2^{n-1}\right) + 2^n,$$  where we "unfolded" the recursion by substituting Equation $(2)$ into Equation $(1)$.  If you do it again, we get

$$T(n) = T(n-3) + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1} + 2^n.$$

This is what you want to write.  The left hand side does not change.

Then a complete unfolding of the recursion gives

$$T(n) = T(0) + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n,$$ and since $T(0) = 1$, we get $$T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = \frac{2^{n+1} - 1}{2-1} = 2^{n+1} - 1,$$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much.